# DVI splitter that can switch between two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, splitter

I have a Wacom 12WG (which is a monitor I can draw on with a stylus) and a monitor, both of them with DVI input. My computer has HDMI output but I can transform it to DVI so no problem getting it all into DVI.

I need a splitter that can switch between my two monitors (1. my primary monitor and 2. my wacom) so that when I want to draw illustrations in Adobe Illustrator my monitor is switched off and my wacom is getting the display stream from my computer. When I want to work, like programming, and play games etc, my monitor is getting the display stream and my wacom is off.
Manually I can handle this by disconnect the DVI cable from the monitor and connect it to the wacom and the other way around.

Basically what I need is a DVI splitter cable with a switch on to switch between my monitors, instead of having to pull out the cable and reconnect it.

And by surprise I havent been able to google it :(

Anyone?

Comment: Search Terms: `dvi splitter for dual monitors` yields http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=dvi%20splitter&Submit=ENE

Comment: but thats not enough. I need to be able to switch between the monitors... not showing both at the same time.